How to modify size of bitmap in layer-list?
I want to have a splash screen in my app that also supports version below android 12. I found this article Jetpack Compose: Splash Screen API. I follow all the steps. But the icon is filling the entire screen as below.
Using android:width,height did not solve the problem (Attribute width is only used in API level 23 and higher (current min is 21)). I'm testing the app in a physical device (Samsung s4 which run android 5.1, cause virtual device is slow).
Other solutions i found was to modify the image size, this caused the image to be noisy.
layer-list
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- res/drawable/splash_background.xml -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Background color -->
<item android:drawable="@color/black" />

<!-- Background image or drawable -->
<item >
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/spotify"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</item>

</layer-list>

theme file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AudioApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <style name="Theme.SplashScreen" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>


</resources>

the SplashActivity
@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
class SplashActivity: ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            delay(3000)
            val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}

This is the output of code, the logo here has a high quality, just because I transferred it from devices.

The spotify logo is 512x512px, when i try to make it smaller it's get distorted using an online image resizer. Here is the exact result it gets blurred and noisy.


To use a splash screen that's compatible with older versions, follow these steps:

Add this dependency to your build.gradle.kts file:

implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")


Update your theme.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AudioApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
    
    <!-- Add this -->
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/black</item> <!-- You can use here @drawable/splash_background -->
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/spotify</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AudioApp</item>
    </style>
</resources>

3.In your AndroidManifest.xml, set the theme of the starting activity to Theme.App.Starting:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


In your MainActivity, call installSplashScreen before super.onCreate():

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        // Your code here
    }
}

If the icon size is incorrect, you can edit it using inkscape.

I don't get the icon using this code, i just get the background
